# icon menu - 1st icon always highlighted

Tags: monodevelop, toolbar, gtk#

I am creating icon menu (toolbar with icons) in gtk# and I do not know why my application always selects (highlights) first icon (every parameter is default). Is there a way to have all icons unhighlighted (highlight only when cursor moves over icon or user clicks on icon)?
Every answer will be very much appreciated.

[image: highlighted icon in gtk#]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it has keyboard focus. You probably want to give another widget the default focus.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - GrabFocus() works great when I use also Entry, but can I disable whole keyboard focus (for the case that I will have only window with toolbar -on application startup)?

Comment: You could set CanFocus=false on that widget, but it would harm keyboard usability of your app.

Comment: The problem is that it is by default false and still this issue remains.

Comment: Now it works - I gave focus for menubar: menubar1.CanFocus=true;
  menubar1.GrabFocus();